# Call to undefined function convert_to_screen() (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, class

i am developing a plugin where i did have to extend the class `WP_List_Table`. I have extended the class within my plugin-file (I don't know if this is the right way to do this?) and included `WP_List_Table` like this:

```
if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}
```

Then comes the code for extending the class and then i do create an instance of my table class like this:

```
$wp_analyzes_table = new RAnalyzes_List_Table();
$wp_analyzes_table->prepare_items();
```

But when i do this, i do get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function convert_to_screen() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\norskeanalyser\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-list-table.php
>   on line 143

I did some research but did not understand how to fix it.

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Best regards.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/convert_to_screen/ did you include the specified source file?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your reply. When i include the source file, i do get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in C:\xampp\htdocs\norskeanalyser\wp-content\plugins\aksjeanalyser\aksjeanalyser.php on line 159. This line looks like this: $screen = get_current_screen();

Comment: Are you sure you loaded all of WordPress? If you are missing two core methods, that might mean you are trying to run WordPress code before it has been loaded in memory. @dahlsdata-tahira

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');
```

to your theme/function.php.
This will solve it.